# Prevent knockout from replacing nested element

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to prevent the content in the span tag from being replaced, after the anchor tag binding takes places?

```
<ul data-bind:"foreach: items">
<li>
<a data-bind="text: name"><span data-bind="text: items().length()"></span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victoryismine06/AZ3Yh/), I'd suggest doing this or placing the name in another `span`

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <a><!--ko text: name--><!--/ko--> <span data-bind="text: items.length"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do either

```
<ul data-bind:"foreach: items">
<li>
<a><span data-bind="text: name"></span> <span data-bind="text: $parent.items().length()"></span></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul data-bind:"foreach: items">
<li>
<a data-bind="text: name() + ' ' + $parent.items().length()"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```